# TFS and Forms Authentication

Tags: tfs, ontime

I don't know squat about TFS, other than as a user who has performed simple check in/outs.

I just installed it locally and would like to do joint development with a friend.

I was having trouble making my TFS web site on port 8080 visible (the whole scoop is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/144273/port-forwarding-why-do-my-local-sites-on-80-work-but-not-those-on-8080) if your interested) and I wonder if it could be related to the fact that TFS is probably using Windows Authentication to identify the user.

**Can TFS be set up to use forms authentication?**

We probably need to set up a VPN, though that's a learning curve too.

**To use TFS, do our machines have to belong to a domain?**

We're not admin types, though he is better than me, though I would be interested in any feedback or advice on which path is likely to pan out the best. I already got AxoSoft OneTime working in this type of an environment and it suits us well, but I am tempted at all the bells & whistles with TFS and the ability to tie tracked bug items to code changes.

**As far as finding a good way to share code, do sites like SourceForge allow one to keep code secure among members only?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not need to be installed in a domain.  I'm running TFS at home within a workgroup on a virtual machine.

Create a user on the machine that hosts TFS.  Let's assume this machine is named TFS-MACHINE.  Grant that user appropriate Team and Project rights.

When connecting to TFS from the remote machine, the user should be prompted for a user ID and password.  They should use a User ID of TFS-MACHINE\username and the appropriate password.

Regarding external spots to host code.  If you're looking for cheap/free, you can look at something like [Unfuddle](http://www.unfuddle.com), which supports SVN and Git.

If you're looking for hosted TFS, the only place I've been able to find thus far is [SaaS Made Easy](http://www.saasmadeeasy.com/), but they can start getting a bit expensive, depending on the number of users you have.

Keep in mind if you're going to host locally that you'll still need to do things like periodic backups, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would prefer to host TFS locally and have a friend access my TFS server via the web. The following is a link which I posted describing an issue I had with putting TFS online. It sounds like you have a good background, o I would welcome your any additional comments that you may be willing to provide. Ty. http://superuser.com/questions/144273/port-forwarding-why-do-my-local-sites-on-80-work-but-not-those-on-8080

Comment: George:  I looked at the stuff you posted on Superuser.Com, and it looks like you got the right stuff.  I'm not sure if this is true with respect to TFS 2010, but I know for sure the default install of TFS 2008 uses ports 8080 *and* 8090 (8080 for the web services, and 8090 for the team system web access). Another consideration (if your router supports it) would be to enable VPN to allow your partner to be able to connect to your network and use the TFS server as if it were on his lan.